# Disabling specific Apache::DBI::db debug messages in Apache2 error.log

Tags: apache, perl, dbi, mod-perl, mod-perl2

How can I disable specific error messages in my Apache2 error.log related to SV = IV, REFCNT, FLAGS, and RV, which refer to Apache::DBI::db? Below is an example of the types of messages I'm receiving:

`SV = IV(0x55bd54a2dcb8) at 0x55bd54a2dcc8   REFCNT = 1   FLAGS = (ROK,READONLY)   RV = 0x55bd541a6f08     SV = PVHV(0x55bd548a0b60) at 0x55bd541a6f08       REFCNT = 1       FLAGS = (OBJECT,OOK,SHAREKEYS)       STASH = 0x55bd517d7bc8    "Apache::DBI::db"       ARRAY = 0x55bd541e9310       KEYS = 0       FILL = 0       MASV = IV(0x55bd544acdf8) at 0x55bd544ace08   REFCNT = 1   FLAGS = (PADMY,ROK)   RV = 0x55bd54829030     SV = PVHV(0x55bd548df550) at 0x55bd54829030       REFCNT = 3       FLAGS = (OBJECT,OOK,SHAREKEYS)       STASH = 0x55bd517d7bc8    "Apache::DBI::db"       ARRAY = 0x55bd54742d10       KEYS = 0       FILL = 0       MAX = 7       RITER = -1       EITER = 0x0`

I set `$Apache::DBI::DEBUG = 0;`, but that didn't change anything.

I'm looking for a way to either resolve or suppress these particular logs.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with sv_dump calls in DBI.xs?

Comment: What is your trace level set to? `DBI->trace( ... )`.

Comment: Something is called Devel::Peek's `Dump` or some C/XS code is calling perlapi's `sv_dump`. Look around for those.

Comment: DBI->trace(0); #is set to 0

Comment: Maybe [this](https://groups.google.com/g/perl.perl5.porters/c/YA86WBIm568) is related?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.